# How is a method "prototype" in ruby documentation interpreted?

Tags: ruby

For example, in the rails api
the following appears:

```
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
```

Coming from a C++/java background, this suggests that all 3 arguments are required: two hashes and a block.  Yet there are numerous examples of this method being used with less than three arguments and with the first argument taking the form of a string.  How does the method template specify the characteristics/type of each argument and which arguments are required?  Is there summary documentation somewhere describing the conventions used to describe how to invoke such methods?

Answer (score 0):

There are no prototypes in the usual sense. In your example

```
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
```

the `form_tag` method expects a maximum of two parameters, but because defaults are supplied for both of them it can be called without any parameters at all. Ruby raises an `ArgumentError` if a method is called with more arguments than have been specified, or fewer arguments than there are parameters with no default.

The type of any default parameter values has no bearing on what may be passed when the method is called, and a call like `form_tag(Math::PI, false)`, while it is unlikely to do anything useful, will compile fine.

Specifying the block in the formal parameters just has the effect of giving named access to any block supplied in the call. It is usually more appropriate to execute the block and pass values to and from it using `yield` within the method. A block is *always* optional when the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, arguments in method prototypes are only required if they are not assigned a default value, and are not a block. Blocks are always optional (though they may not be optional in terms of method implementation). Consider the following:

```
def foo(bar, baz = nil, bin = :bang, &block)
```

In this example, `bar` is required, since it doesn't receive a default value if it's not assigned. If you don't want to specify further parameters, you don't have to - `baz` will be assigned `nil`, and `bin` will be assigned `:bang`.

You can pass values for just `foo` and `baz`, too, neglecting `bin` and letting it receive its default: `foo(:some_bar, :some_baz)`.

If you wanted to pass a value for `bin`, but not for `baz`, you get stuck, though - Ruby won't let you pass values for arguments 1 & 3 and skip 2. To reach argument 3, you have to pass argument 2, so your invocation might be `foo(:some_bar, nil, :boom)`.

Blocks, as mentioned, are always optional. Semantically, a block might be required. For example, if you have

```
def foo(&block)
  yield
end
```

And you invoke foo without a block, you'll receive `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`. If your method requires a block to run, then this is probably appropriate since it informs the user that they didn't pass a block. However, if the block may be optional, then you can test if one was passed with `block_given?`, so you can adjust your method's implementation based on whether or not an argument was passed.

Answer (score -1):

Any type can be an argument. The first two arguments will default to empty hashes and the '&' variable will capture the block. [This explains default arguments pretty well.](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/)